# Final Fantasy 8 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, final-fantasy-8

So I bought a copy of Final Fantasy 8 today, and it won't install. The startup program works just fine, but when I click to install, the setup program won't run. Any help would be appreciated. I'm running Windows 8, by the way.
Thanks!

Comment: It works fine for me, are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Searching around the [net](http://intangibility.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=403), I found something which you should try:

Run the setup.exe using [compatibility mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/get-apps-devices-working) XP SP2